# Swift - How to get CPU load properly

Tags: swift, macos, cpu

I'm trying to get the current CPU load as a percentage, but when I try with the code below, the data I get is absurd

```swift
print(stats.cpu_ticks)
```

not much changes

| time | cpu_tick[0] | cpu_tick[1] | cpu_tick[2] | cpu_tick[3] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1s | 1810101 | 782080 | 22191087 | 0 |
| 2s | 1810214 | 782122 | 22191725 | 0 |
| 3s | 1810322 | 782158 | 22192376 | 0 |

```swift
print("\tSYSTEM:          \(Int(cpuUsage.system))%")
print("\tUSER:            \(Int(cpuUsage.user))%")
print("\tIDLE:            \(Int(cpuUsage.idle))%")
print("\tNICE:            \(Int(cpuUsage.nice))%")
```

and here nothing change

| time | system | user | idle | nice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1s | 3% | 7% | 89% | 0% |
| 2s | 3% | 7% | 89% | 0% |
| 3s | 3% | 7% | 89% | 0% |

Load info struct

```swift
  fileprivate static func hostCPULoadInfo() -> host_cpu_load_info {
    var info = host_cpu_load_info_data_t()
    var count = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<host_cpu_load_info>.stride / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride)
    
    let kerr: kern_return_t = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &info, {
      host_statistics(mach_host_self(), HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO, $0.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: 1, { $0 }), &count)
    })
    
    guard kerr == KERN_SUCCESS else {
      return host_cpu_load_info()
    }
    
    return info
  }
```

```swift
  private mutating func cpuUsage() -> (system: Double, user: Double, idle: Double, nice: Double) {
    let stats = LoadInfo.hostCPULoadInfo()
    
    print(stats.cpu_ticks)
    
    let userDiff = stats.cpu_ticks.0 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.0
    let systemDiff = stats.cpu_ticks.1 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.1
    let idleDiff = stats.cpu_ticks.2 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.2
    let niceDiff = stats.cpu_ticks.3 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.3
    
    let totalTicks = UInt64(systemDiff + userDiff + idleDiff + niceDiff)
    
    let onePercent = Double(totalTicks / 100)
    
    let system = Double(systemDiff) / onePercent
    let user = Double(userDiff) / onePercent
    let idle = Double(idleDiff) / onePercent
    let nice = Double(niceDiff) / onePercent
    
    loadPrevious = stats
    
    return (system, user, idle, nice)
  }
```

```swift
  public func getCPUUsage() {
    var test = LoadInfo()
    let cpuUsage = test.cpuUsage()
    print("\tSYSTEM:          \(Int(cpuUsage.system))%")
    print("\tUSER:            \(Int(cpuUsage.user))%")
    print("\tIDLE:            \(Int(cpuUsage.idle))%")
    print("\tNICE:            \(Int(cpuUsage.nice))%")
  }
```

This is how this function is called (every second)

```
  private func updateStatistics() {
    loadInfo.getCPUUsage()
  }
```

Comment: Those numbers don't seem absurd. What results are you expecting?

Comment: @TomHarrington I would like the current CPU load but at the moment with this code it shows me constant load, while in Activity Monitor the Idle itself changes every second, say in the range of 70%-95%, for example, idle in the activity monitor is 60% and this code still returns me 89%

Comment: @4c65736975 Where and when does `loadPrevious` get its initial value? I tried your code-- along with my best guess about `loadPrevious`-- and I get different results on each call to `getCPUUsage()`.

Comment: @TomHarrington Just above cpuUsage func fileprivate var loadPrevious = host_cpu_load_info()

Comment: @4c65736975 My best guess was `var loadPrevious: host_cpu_load_info = hostCPULoadInfo()`, which does not produce the same numbers every time when I try it. I don't know why that's different though.

Comment: @TomHarrington It didn't help, but it made me think and I realized that my mistake was absurd, every time getCPUUsage() was called it created a new LoadInfo instance, so no LoadPreviouse was stored at all... a real shame. Thank you very much for your help, have a peaceful and happy Christmas

Comment: You can post your own solution as an answer to help others.

Comment: @soundflix Of course I will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the provided code works well with data of similar accuracy to Activity Monitor

```swift
  fileprivate static func hostCPULoadInfo() -> host_cpu_load_info {
    var info = host_cpu_load_info_data_t()
    var count = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<host_cpu_load_info>.stride / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride)
    
    let kerr: kern_return_t = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &info, {
      host_statistics(mach_host_self(), HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO, $0.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: 1, { $0 }), &count)
    })
    
    guard kerr == KERN_SUCCESS else {
      return host_cpu_load_info()
    }
    
    return info
  }

  var loadPrevious: host_cpu_load_info = hostCPULoadInfo()

  private mutating func cpuUsage() -> (system: Double, user: Double, idle: Double, nice: Double) {
    let stats = LoadInfo.hostCPULoadInfo()
    
    print(stats.cpu_ticks)
    
    let userDiff = stats.cpu_ticks.0 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.0
    let systemDiff = stats.cpu_ticks.1 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.1
    let idleDiff = stats.cpu_ticks.2 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.2
    let niceDiff = stats.cpu_ticks.3 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.3
    
    let totalTicks = UInt64(systemDiff + userDiff + idleDiff + niceDiff)
    
    let onePercent = Double(totalTicks / 100)
    
    let system = Double(systemDiff) / onePercent
    let user = Double(userDiff) / onePercent
    let idle = Double(idleDiff) / onePercent
    let nice = Double(niceDiff) / onePercent
    
    loadPrevious = stats
    
    return (system, user, idle, nice)
  }
```

The problem was caused by creating a new LoadInfo instance in the getCPUUsage function every time it was called, so none of the LoadPreviouse data was properly used. All we need to do is simply get rid of the getCPUUsage function and for example in our view structure or wherever we need CPU usage data, create a LoadInfo instance and simply call the cpuUsage function e.g. like this

```swift
  @State private var loadInfo = LoadInfo()

  private func getCPUUsage() {
    let cpuUsage = loadInfo.cpuUsage()
    print("\tSYSTEM:          \(Int(cpuUsage.system))%")
    print("\tUSER:            \(Int(cpuUsage.user))%")
    print("\tIDLE:            \(Int(cpuUsage.idle))%")
    print("\tNICE:            \(Int(cpuUsage.nice))%")
  }
```

Comment: Wait `private mutating func cpuUsage()` — was it in `struct` and therefore each time `loadPrevious` was set it was a different instance?

Comment: @user28434'mstep The `public func getCPUUsage()` was in the structure and as you can see, it created a new instance every time it was called